# Separable differentiable equations

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Which of the following is a solution to the separable differentiable equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{xy}{\ln y }$$

$A.\ \displaystyle e^{|x|}$

$B.\ \displaystyle e^{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}2}}$

$C.\ \displaystyle \frac12$$e^{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

$D.\ \displaystyle e^{-x}$

What I did was separate the functions and get:

$$\frac{\ln y\ dy}{y}=x\ dx$$

Then integrating I get:

$$\frac{\ln^2 y}{2} = \frac{x^2}{2} + C$$

But that doesn't match any of my answers. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: The statement of the problem is a bit weak -- it should ask you for an _explicit_ function $ \ y \ = \ f(x) \ $ that would solve the differential equation.  So you want to solve your result for $ \ y \ $ as some function of $ \ x \ $  on the right-hand side; keep in mind that " _a_ solution of the differential equation" means that the arbitrary constant $ \ C \ $ can take on a specific value.

Comment: Yeah I think the problem is simply asking for the equation without C in it although it should really be in there. Like they would normally give " for a value F(3) = 5" or something like that. But I think this is asking for the samething just without C in it.,

Comment: Any function with the correct form and _some_ value for $  \ C \ $ would be a solution, so the choice should be a function with the correct form.  Let me know if I edited any of your choices incorrectly.

Comment: Yeah I just don't know how to do this problem or if its even do-able. But yes you did edit them properly. Sorry for my poor mathjax skills :p

Comment: What **B.S.** shows is correct:  multiply your result by 2 on both sides, take the square-root of both sides, and then "exponentiate" both sides. That gives the general solution to the differential equation.  Do any of your choices resemble that (with a numerical value for $ \ C \ $ inserted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right. We have:

$$\frac{\ln^2 y}{2}=\frac{x^2}{2}+C$$

Now multiply both sides by $2$:

$$\ln^2 y = x^2+C$$

**NOTE**: $C$ is *any* arbitrary constant, so we'll just make $2C=C$ because it doesn't really matter (still some constant).

Now you want to isolate for $y$, that's how you'll get the solution. Hence, first take the square root of both sides so you'll be 1 step closer:

$$\ln y = \sqrt{x^2+C}$$

And remember the definition of the natural logarithm. This can be turned into:

$$y=e^\sqrt{x^2+C}$$

Remember that $C$ can be any number, so you can figure it out now.

Answer (score 3):

$$\ln^2(y)=x^2+C\to \ln(y)=\pm\sqrt{x^2+C}\to y=\exp(\pm\sqrt{x^2+C})$$

Comment: that made no sense to me... :(

Comment: Makes a whole lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

Here this might help:

Okay, so the first thing you do is:

Separate variables on either sides of the equation:

$$\frac{\ln y dy}{y} = x dx$$

If we integrate notice that if we make $u = \ln y$

$$udu = xdx$$

And it becomes an easy integral:
$$\frac{\ln^2 y}{2} = \frac{x^2}{2} + C$$

Multiply both sides by 2:

$$\ln^2 y = x^2 + 2C$$

It doesn't matter what C is, so $C = 2C$ in this instance.

Continuing:

$$\ln y = \sqrt{x^2+C}$$
$$y = e^{\sqrt{x^2+C}}$$

**EDIT**

The answer can be either A or D, depending on how you look at it.

Comment: How does the constant term escape ending up under the radical?

Comment: Your last two equations have incorrect exponents

Comment: @RecklessReckoner oops didn't mean for that too happen, forget formatting :D

Comment: But how would the $\frac12$ get there?

Comment: @Shahar which $\frac{1}{2}$ are you referring to

Comment: @VarunIyer In answer choice C.

Comment: Yeah 1/2 just randomly is supposed to appear. Theres no sense in how that comes into the answer. B seems more correct to me...

Comment: @Panthy I didn't see the $\frac{1}{2}$ my mistake. The answer isn't C then. I do not see a right answer. My work isn't correct and is in accordance with the other answers stated already as well.

Comment: @Panthy The answer is D. You end up having $y=e^\sqrt{x^2+C}$. If $C=0$, then you have $y=e^\sqrt{x^2}$. $\sqrt{x^2}=\pm x$.

Comment: @Shahar but **NOTE THAT** $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$ as well. So answer can be A too.

Comment: Maybe A is a safer choice since if x is a negative number D would not work out...

Comment: @VarunIyer Oh I didn't refresh the page. Before the new edit, choice A had what seemed to be spaces instead of absolute value bars. But cool catch, there's no correct answer then.